# Pyspark + Hadoop + Anaconda install

Tags: apache-spark, anaconda

I'm new to Anaconda, Spark and Hadoop. I wanted to get a standalone dev environment setup on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine but was getting confused on what I do within conda and what is external.

So far I had installed Anaconda and created a Tensorflow environment (I will be using TF too I should add), and installed PySpark separately outside of Anaconda.

However I wasn't sure if that's what I'm supposed to do or whether I am supposed to use conda install? I'm also eventually going to want to install Hortonwork's Hadoop too - and hear that may already come bundled with spark.

Long story short - I just want to get a dev environment set up with all these technologies that I can play around with and have data flow from one to the other as seamlessly as possible.

Appreciate any advice on the "correct" way to set everything up.

Comment: is it an option to just use a vendor's VM?
Cloudera, MapR and Hortonworks all provide one with everything preinstalled and configured

Comment: Thanks I'm just trying to get my head round whether a Hortonworks Sandbox is the same as a Dev environment. I.e. Could I develop things locally on it using small amounts of data then migrate my solution to the cloud. Or to put it differently, what do professionals use for a dev environment when doing big data dev work on their local machines?

Comment: Actually I think the answer might be yes based on this so I'll close off the question. https://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/setting-spark-development-environment-python/    (Not sure how to award the points it to you though

Comment: usually companies have dedicated clusters running. Then they either split it up logically or physically. Due to compliance, rarely does data leave the datalake/clusters to local machines.
But for testing purposes, you can just use a virtual cluster like the VM's or just spin up some nodes on amazon (if you are willing to fork them over some money ;) ) Or you install one yourself using old computers you might have lying around.